# why is this "Unknown type name 'MoodPrefetchOp'; did you mean 'PrefetchOp'?" showing? Both files h and m exist

Tags: ios

My app was working until all of sudden I get this infamous warning. 
I've tried everything from updating to the latest Xcode 11.3.1. 
I've updated to Catalina OS, and I even removed the cocoa pods.

Finally, I just rebuilt the project from scratch adding the necessary files to the project. Of course Apple doesn't provide any insight on developers forum. The object's H file exist along with it's M file. I noticed this little gremlin in XCODE even tried to say one of my object file was an Integer and not the designated object I had  originally created it. What gives? [error-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAxUs.png)

Comment: I guess you've cleaned the build folder?

Answer (score 0):

well, after hours of working, I thank GOD he revealed what to do... in one word, "rebuild" from scratch. I had cocoa pods, in my project, so that made it even more difficult. Once I rebuilt it from scratch, it started working.  when I say "rebuild", just import your files into a new project.  If you are not using features in cocoa, I strongly recommend deleting them from your project. It causes future problems.